# Unirest response returning a website?

Tags: php, laravel-4, unirest, mashape

I'm trying to get Unirest working on my Laravel 4.0 framework.

Right now I'm using REST Countries v1 API and I'm having this issue while trying to get all countries:
http://i.gyazo.com/3876755ebdf9b3e71c03a0e801975053.png
if I remove the authorization, it returns a normal response saying to authorize but as soon as I authorize and try to get all countries it throws the whole mashape website on my localhost page.

```
<?php
Unirest::verifyPeer(false);
$response = Unirest::get(
    "https://restcountries-v1.p.mashape.com", // This should return ALL the countries
    array(
        "X-Mashape-Authorization" => "secret-code"
    ),
    null
);
?>
{{ $response->raw_body }} // echo $response->raw_body
```

But when I try to get by country code, it works like expected

```
<?php
Unirest::verifyPeer(false);
$response = Unirest::get(
    "https://restcountries-v1.p.mashape.com/alpha/ru", // This should return only russia
    array(
         "X-Mashape-Authorization" => "secret-code"
    ),
    null
);
?>
{{ $response->raw_body }} //echo $response->raw_body
```

http://i.gyazo.com/72017ce438f91cab8c9b16c50bba12d3.png

Why doesn't the first code example work but rather echo the whole Mashape website??

Comment: I have the same issue when attempting to figure this out. It appears that ``https://restcountries-v1.p.mashape.com/`` responds with headers ``HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily`` and it redirects to ``https://www.mashape.com/fayder/REST-Countries-v1`` which would explain why it's echoing out the entire page. Maybe you should submit it as an issue.